# isValidUrl source code?

Tags: android

Where can I get the source code of this method in android :  URLUtil.isValidUrl() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/webkit/URLUtil.java#URLUtil.isValidUrl%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You can get code here : [URLUtil](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/webkit/URLUtil.java#URLUtil) but i don't think it will be useful (sorry I haven't seen the other response with the same link)